# Remove images from content in wordpress gallery template

Tags: wordpress, gallery, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add a gallery template to a child theme and am finding it frustratingly difficult to find good examples. The best example I've found to date is by [Andres Hermosilla](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-your-own-image-gallery-page-template-in-wordpress--wp-23721), but was made way back in 2012.

Steps 1 to 3 will get me half of what I want, which is a gallery inserted above the site title (I don't need fluxslider or similar at this stage.) The following is the code I'm using, placed just before `the_title()`:

```
<?php

$image_args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1, // Using -1 loads all posts
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', // This ensures images are in the order set in the page media manager
    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', // Make sure it doesn't pull other resources, like videos
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, // Important part - ensures the associated images are loaded
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);

$images = get_children( $image_args );
if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $image ) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image->guid; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->post_title; ?>" title="<?php echo $image->post_title; ?>" />
    <?php    }
} ?>
```

My issue is that the images themselves remain displayed in the content of the post - how can I strip all of the images from the page content at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a class to the gallery template page and display none all the images except for gallery ones using css.